# Crystal Reports vs. WinForms issue

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a WinForms app (written in VB.NET if that detail matters) which has an embedded Crystal Report for tracking application utilization (let's call it utr310.rpt). Our reporting guy made a minor tweak to the report that has been in production and I'm trying to test with it (let's call the new one utr311.rpt) except that I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80043AE3): Invalid TLV record.
   at CRAXDRT.IApplication.OpenReport(String pFileName, Object OpenMethod)
   at WinFormsApp422.mCrystal.CrystalReportShowSingleParameter(String sReportName, Object objParam, Boolean& bPrint) in C:\2008-Projects\WinForms-applications\WinFormsApp422\code_Modules\mCrystal.vb:line 161
```

I cannot make heads or tails of this error. Any of y'all seen this one?

Answer (score 0):

a couple of questions for you?

1. What changes were made?
2. Did the developer use the same version to change the report as VB.NET is using?
3. Can you open the report at the location using the developers crystal report developer and the version you have in VB?
4. Is the report file size greater than zero?
5. Is the path correct?

Comment: 1. A subreport -- the second or third of it's kind -- was added to the report.
2. The last two times I asked the crystal dude, he says he's using the same version of crystal as ever. How do I prove/disprove that?
3. Yes.
4. Yes.
5. Yes.